# Git Clone hangs after Proxy is set

Tags: git

I've followed the various guides around setting the git proxy, but I still cant get this working.

I am trying to clone from a VDI behind a corporate firewall & proxy. I have install Cygwin with git packaged up on pretty much a clean Windows 10 install.

Git Version: 2.17.0

I have inspected and pulled out the proxy URL:PORT and added these to my GIT config. Looking at the PAC file I can see no indication of any credentials being required.

Before adding the proxy config I get the expected output: 'Could not resolve host : gitlab.xxx.com'

After adding to the global config:

```
$ git config --global http.proxy <host>:<port>
```

This gives me the error: 'Received HTTP Code 407 from Proxy after CONNECT'

If I set: `$ git config --global sslVerify "false"` Then try again I am still unable to clone with git hanging on the 'Cloning into xxx' message until it eventually times out.

Adding '--verbose' provides no extra information as to why it is hanging. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A 407 code means that proxy authentication is required.  When you specify a proxy using the `http_proxy` environment variable or using `http.proxy`, you need to specify the username (and optionally, password) in the string.  You may also need to provide `http.proxyAuth` if your proxy offers authentication methods that will not result in a successful connection.

A PAC file is used across multiple systems and users, and doesn't contain a way to specify that authentication is needed or required, or which credentials to use.  When used in a web browser, the browser will prompt for credentials, but most command-line programs will not.  Git will only prompt you for a password if you specify a username; otherwise, it assumes the proxy is unauthenticated.

Comment: any way I can determine my proxy credentials? Looking at Network & Internet > Proxy settings it points at the PAC file.

Comment: They may be stored in your browser or operating system's keychain or credential store.  On macOS, it's Keychain; I don't know what it is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Write this to your **.gitconfig** file and check if it works.

I use this config to connect to github through proxy.(Works in linux)

```
[http]
    proxy = http://username:password@host:port
[user]
    name = <username>
    email = <your_email>
```